# Creating a simple printf function in C without using stdarg.h library

Tags: c, pointers, printf

I've been working on making a very simple printf function in c that does the following: it prints strings, signed integers, unsigned integers and the % symbol. Every implementation I have checked uses a the stdarg.h library. However, I am trying the do it without. The problem is that I am unsure how I would implement a variable number of arguments in the printf. The only method so far that I have come up with is to use pointers for the arguments and try to increment them. This approach doesn't seem to work.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_int(int n) {
    if (n < 0) {
        putchar('-');
        n = -n;
    }
    if (n / 10)
        print_int(n / 10);
    putchar(n % 10 + '0');
}

void print_uint(unsigned int n) {
    if (n / 10)
        print_uint(n / 10);
    putchar(n % 10 + '0');
}

void print_string(char *s) {
    while (*s)
        putchar(*s++);
}

void my_printf(char *format, ...) {
    void **arg = (void **) &format + 1;

    for (char *p = format; *p; p++) {
        if (*p != '%') {
            putchar(*p);
            continue;
        }

        switch (*++p) {
            case 'd':
                print_int(*(int *) arg++);
                break;
            case 'u':
                print_uint(*(unsigned int *) arg++);
                break;
            case 's':
                print_string(*(char **) arg++);
                break;
            case '%':
                putchar('%');
                break;
            default:
                putchar(*p);
                break;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int x = 42;
    unsigned int y = 1234567890;
    char *s = "Hello, world!";

    my_printf("Testing my_printf:\n");
    my_printf("Signed integer: %d\n", x);
    my_printf("Unsigned integer: %u\n", y);
    my_printf("String: %s\n", s);
    my_printf("Percent sign: %%\n");

    return 0;
}
```

The output I get from running this is:

````
Testing my_printf:
Signed integer: 849754744
Unsigned integer: 849754744
String: Y�Ź�U
Percent sign: %```


How can I fix this?
````

Comment: The way you access variable numbers of arguments in C is via `<stdarg.h>`.  If you aren't willing to use `<stdarg.h>`: (a) think again; (b) rethink once more; (c) keep rethinking until you reach sanity; (d) if your course-work requires you not to use `<stdarg.h>`, say so; (e) you're about to embark on a world of hurt, and your solution will be tied to the specific platform where you develop your code, at least until you port it to every other ABI (application binary interface).  Don't do this unless you can't persuade your tutors otherwise; then do a minimal reimplementation of `<stdarg.h>`.

Comment: Once upon a time, when everything was passed on the stack, you could write your own code to pop variable arguments back off the stack (sort of like you're doing) pretty straightforwardly.  These days, with some arguments being passed in registers (but which ones?), this is basically impossible, and using `<stdarg.h>` — which ends up hooking into magic things that only the compiler can do — is really the **only** option.

Answer (score 3):

The way you access variable numbers of arguments in C is via `<stdarg.h>`.

If you aren't willing to use `<stdarg.h>`:

- think again;
- rethink once more;
- keep rethinking until you reach sanity;
- if your course-work requires you not to use `<stdarg.h>`, say so;
- you're about to embark on a world of hurt, and your solution will be tied to the specific platform where you develop your code, at least until you port it to every other ABI (application binary interface).

Don't do this unless you can't persuade your tutors otherwise.  If you must do it, do a minimal reimplementation of `<stdarg.h>`, using parallel but different names (for the header and the types, macros and functions defined therein).  It is much harder these days than it would have been 30 years ago.

Comment: I miss reading your answers (:

Answer (score 1):

The details of how to read variadic arguments passed to a function are highly implementation specific.

The **only** way to portably implement a function with variadic arguments is
via the functions defined in `stdargs.h`.

Comment: Re “The **only** way to properly implement…”: That must mean all the implementations of `stdarg.h` are improper, as they must implement variadic arguments by means other than `stdarg.h`. Did you mean portable, not proper?

Answer (score 0):

Well... `<stdarg.h>` could look something like this:

```
// Personally I abhor '#pragma once' but I do not want to get
// into a discussion about what include guard name would be
// appropriate

#pragma once

typedef __builtin_va_list va_list;
#define va_arg( ap, type ) ( __builtin_va_arg( ap, type ) )
#define va_copy( dest, src ) ( __builtin_va_copy( dest, src ) )
#define va_end( ap ) ( __builtin_va_end( ap ) )
#define va_start( ap, parmN ) ( __builtin_va_start( ap, parmN ) )
```

...because, basically, *only the compiler actually knows* how variable argument lists *really* work on your selected platform, given your selected compiler options etc. etc.

So... you could write the above into a `<stdarg.h>` of your own -- which might or might not agree with whatever else you are using / not using in the way of standard headers -- or you could do **the sensible thing** and **just use `<stdarg.h>`** as your environment provides it.